# add to cart button disappear if I use quntity feild

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add "quantity field" for each product in shop page

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        // Access the cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
        // If we have match update quantity
        if($product_id == $product->get_ID()) {
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array('input_value' => $quantity), $product, false );
        } else {
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        }
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

**It works, but the problem is; If I use the quantity field and pressed add to cart button, the button will disappear, and ONLY when deleting the cart the add to cart button will show up again.**

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have just tested and worked fine for me. Which theme you are using?

Comment: Yes, I have checked. The issue is there on site. It's required to debug.

Comment: It only appears to happen after the functionality was used multiple times ...? I can see the buttons disappearing, when I clicked add to cart two or three times; doesn't appear to matter on which product(s) or which quantity(?). The logical conclusion would be that your if conditions there are not fulfilled any more, so you should start debugging by checking what each of them returns individually.

Comment: I have checked more find out that it's only happened when qty is more than >= 4.

Comment: `if($product_id == $product->get_ID())` - this can only be true, if the new item you are trying to add, happens to be the _last_ item already in your cart. Because you are _overwriting_ `$product_id` (and `$quantity`) all the time in that prior loop over the current cart content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the foreach loop

```
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        // Access the cart items
        $in_cart = false;
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
            if($product_id == $product->get_ID()){
                $in_cart = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If we have match update quantity
        if($in_cart) {
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array('input_value' => $quantity), $product, false );
        } else {
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        }
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```